# How to count number of observations in each column in a grouped dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe composed of geochemical samples result which includes the following variables:

```
Year, Zone, *48 analyzed elements*, *more information*.
```

I want to know how many samples were collected each year, in each zone for every elements. So basically, I would like a table that would look like this:

```
Year,Zone,Ag_ppm, ..., Zr_ppm
1981, ZoneA, 0, ..., 0 
1981, ZoneB, 20, ..., 0
1983, ZoneA, 0, ..., 150
```

I have tried the following:

```
 Elt_count <- SoilGeology %>%
  group_by(Year, Zone) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm),funs(sum)) %>%
  select(Year, Zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)
```

It works but it does not give me the information I want (I don't want the cummulative sum of the samples , but a count of every samples).
I have then tried:

```
Elt_count <- SoilGeology %>%
  group_by(Year, Zone) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm),funs(n)) %>%
  select(Year, Zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)
```

But I get the following error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :`n()`does not take arguments`

I have also tried:

```
d <- SoilGeology %>%
  group_by(Year, Zone) %>%
  summarise_all(n) %>%
  select(Year, Zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)
```

But I get the same error as above: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :`n()`does not take arguments`

And also tried with count:

```
Elt_count <- SoilGeology %>%
  group_by(Year, Zone) %>%
  count(Au_ppm:Zr_ppm, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(Year, Zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)
```

But, I get the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: NA/NaN argument.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Au_ppm:Zr_ppm :
  numerical expression has 52 elements: only the first used
2: In Au_ppm:Zr_ppm :
  numerical expression has 52 elements: only the first used
```

Does someone has an explanation for these errors? Or a better solution for my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a little data reproducibly? Something we can copy/paste is nicest. `dput(Elt_count[1:8, 1:5])` would be good to give us the first 8 rows and first 5 columns. Then also show the output you want? I don't quite understand what you mean... `sum` will add up the values, it's different than `cumsum` which would do the cumulative sum. `n()` will be the number rows, which is the same for every column in each group. `count()` will do the same thing as `n()`. (And, if you look at the help page `?count`, it doesn't take a `na.rm` argument.

Comment: Maybe you want a count of the non-zero values? Is that your goal?

Comment: @Gregor, yes, I would like a count of non-zero values for all my variables (geochemical elements) in my groups (by Year and Zone).
 `sum` and `cumsum` do not produce the result that I want. I just tried it because `n` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` adds numbers, `n()` and `count()` count rows. If numbers greater than 0 have special meaning for you, you need to tell R that. The classic way to count the number of things meeting a condition is `sum(..test for condition..)`, so if you want the number of elements of `x` that are greater than `0`, `sum(x > 0)` will do it. This is the function you want to apply to all columns:

```
# reproducible example on built-in data
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(disp:carb), function(x) sum(x > 5))

# for your data
Elt_count <- SoilGeology %>%
  group_by(Year, Zone) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm), function(x) sum(x > 0))
```

I don't know your data. You may want to change it to `sum(x != 0)` if there are negative numbers you want to count too. If there are missing values, `sum(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE)` (if you look at `?sum`, it does take a `na.rm` argument).

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! 
Can you please explain how you used `function(x) sum(x>0)` . I have not seen this syntax before.

Comment: That's an "anoynymous function"---a function I only intend to use once so we don't bother naming it. You could just as well create a function `count_gt_0 = function(x) {sum(x > 0)}` and then use `summarise_at(vars(Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm), sum_gt_0)`. That's what you should do if you need to count things greater than 0 a lot. But for single or rare use, (and short simple things) anonymous functions nice.

Comment: See also [anonymous functions at Advanced R Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following code is what you desire.

`library(dplyr)
count(SoilGeology, year, zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)`

Or equivalently with the pipe function

`SoilGeology %>% count(SoilGeology, year, zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm)`

Alternately,

`SoilGeology %>% 
  group_by(year, zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm) %>%
  summarise(number = n())`

Or

`SoilGeology %>% 
  group_by(year, zone, Ag_ppm:Zr_ppm) %>%
  tally()`

If errors persist, the 'class()' of your variables should be checked. Values may need to be coerced to numeric. If needed, try `variable -> as.numeric(variable)` and try again.

Comment: OP clarified in comments that they want to count the number of non-zero values in each column.